# Uncaught ReferenceError in jquery code compiled from coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, referenceerror

I have the following jquery code (compiled from coffee script).

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $.get('/proteins', function(proteins) {});
  });
  $.each(proteins, function(index, protein) {
    return $('#proteins').append($("<li>").text(protein.name));
  });
}).call(this);
```

The coffeescript that generated this code looks like this:

```
$ ->
  $.get '/proteins', (proteins) ->
    $.each proteins, (index, protein) ->
     $('#proteins').append $("<li>").text protein.name
```

I keep getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: proteins is not defined" at line 6 of my generated code.

Am I missing something (very basic) here?

Thanks!!

Comment: CoffeeScript looks correct. It looks to me like an indentation error; JS looks like what you'd get if the `$.each` line was not more indented than `$.get` line. Check that you don't have a tab somewhere?

Comment: I don't know coffescript but that JS doesn't look right. There's a function which gets the proteins but doesn't do anything with the value. `$.each(proteins...` needs to be inside `function(proteins) {here}`

Comment: I think your indentation is not correct, there is only 1 space diff between `$.each` and `$('#proteins')`

Comment: You almost certainly have a tab indenting `$.each` and spaces elsewhere.

Comment: whitespace; it'll get you every time. try making sure you are using an editor with coffeescript support and replacing tabs with spaces.

Comment: Thank you Amadan, artm, Arun & Jed. This is an indentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tab indenting $.each and spaces elsewhere. Indentation is not correct. Use an editor with coffeescript support.